# Add additional field to lookup field inside schema.xml

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

I'm following the steps in this article to setup a joined data view webpart joined on a lookup field:

http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/joined-subviews-with-linked-datasources-in-sharepoint-2010/

To summarize these steps, I need to expose the ID column as an additional field in the lookup:

[image]

*(image copied from linked blog post above)*

---

I'm creating my lists and lookup columns declaratively inside a Visual Studio solution, and I would like to add this additional field in the xml.  How do I do this?

The xml definition for my lookup field is as follows:

```
<Field ID="{5D184D01-082C-4831-8757-CA2C98F05221}"  
       Name="EventInquiry"  
       DisplayName="Event Inquiry"  
       Type="Lookup"  
       Required="FALSE"  
       Group="Ops Inquiry Tracking Columns"  
       ShowField="EventCode"  
       List="Lists/Event Inquirys"></Field>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To setup the additional field from the lookup, you need to add a second lookup field pointing at the same list, but include the `FieldRef` attribute on the second lookup field.  The value of this attribute should be the same as the `ID` attribute of the first lookup field.

```
<Field ID="{393F697A-7F99-488E-B67F-41DFD6D41857}" 
       FieldRef="{5D184D01-082C-4831-8757-CA2C98F05221}"  
       Name="EventInquiryID"  
       DisplayName="Event Inquiry:ID"  
       Type="Lookup"  
       Required="FALSE"  
       ShowField="ID"  
       List="Lists/Event Inquirys"></Field>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the example provided on http://sharpointpractice.blogspot.nl/2011/08/sharepoint-field-types-elementsxml.html worked to get the second field from the lookup.