# Lookup field with formatted text

Tags: 2013, development, lookup-column

I've created several lookup fields programmatically in existing lists, currently they render with just one field as the text value, however I'd like them to display the contents of two text fields rather than just one, is there a way to do this without adding an additional column into the source field

i.e. display this

```
001 - Title 1
002 - Title 2
003 - Title 3
```

instead of this

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of getting what you want:

1. You can have the addition information in the source field used in the lookup
2. You can add additional columns to you list see [Add additional field to lookup field inside schema.xml](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59159/add-additional-field-to-lookup-field-inside-schema-xml)
3. You can use jslink to format the display of your column see [Client-Side Rendering/JS Link documentation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/client-side-rendering-js-link-documentation)

Comment: Thanks Per, any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: I'd have liked to do this with C# but given you've got me a method to do this, I'll accept it as the answer